# Explanation for the Ray Optics Regime

Tags: optics, refraction

I'm studying Optical Tweezers. When a laser is goes through a transparent object, its reflection and refraction can be calculated by Ray Optics as long as the object is much larger than the wavelenght of light .

Why is this a condition?  Why won't the Ray Model work if the object's size is comparable to or much smaller than the wavelenght?

The same condition apears when calculation refraction of light by lenses and I don't get the physics.

TIA

Answer (score 1):

Ray optics ignores wave diffraction effects. A ballpark figure for the deviation of waves from straight line is: $\theta \approx \frac{\lambda}{d}$ where $d$ is the object size. The condition you quote makes sure the deviation from straight ray is negligible.